# Как задать значение переменной path в c++ qt?

Tags: c++, qt, path

Нужно задать переменной path пути к библиотекам используемым в программе. Как это сделать?

Comment: В строке "Поиск" выполните поиск: Система (Панель управления)
Нажмите на ссылку Дополнительные параметры системы.
Нажмите Переменные среды. В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную среды PATH. Нажмите Изменить. Если переменной PATH не существует, нажмите Создать.
В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH. Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК. Изменения вступят в силу после перезагрузки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или запустить cmd через права администратора и ввести следующую команду

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path\here\
```

Answer (score 1):

Если пишете на Qt в Qt-creator, то лучше задать PATH через него.

Для этого:

1. Откройте свой проект в Qt-creator.
2. Перейдите в "Проекты"->"Запуск"->"Среда выполнения".
3. Найдите PATH и добавьте туда нужный путь кнопкой "Изменить".

[image: Изменение PATH через Qt-creator]

Comment: Если делать через qt то для каждого проекта где будет использоваться данная библиотека нужно будет прописывать path. Не рационально. З.Ы Это только моя точка мнения.

Comment: @jNX, можно в настройках кита прописать раз и навсегда. `Tools->Options->Kits-><Интересующий кит>->Environment`